# Audio peer to peer streaming on android

Tags: android, audio, p2p

i am building a Playlists managment app for android.

As a part of the app i want to be able to stream a song throgh P2P connection (no server in the middle) from one phone to the other.
i would like to do so with regular cellular company internet and not to be obligated to have both phones on the same wifi.

does anypne have a good way for doing that?